# calculus of natural deduction

Tags: logic

1. What is the most natural formulation (without contexts) of the $\leftrightarrow$-introduction? Maybe $\begin{array}{c}
   A\rightarrow B \quad B \rightarrow A\\
   \hline\hline
   A\leftrightarrow B
   \end{array}$?
2. Why is not $A$ allowed to be dependent of a formula in which $x$ is a free variable (exception: $A$ is dependent of $\varphi(x)$) in the $\exists$-elimination-rule $\begin{array}{c}
   \exists x(\varphi(x)) \quad \varphi(x)\vdash A\\
   \hline
   A
   \end{array}$?

$A\vdash B$ means the same as

$[A]$

$ \ \ \vdots$

$ \ B$

Comment: If $A\vdash B$, $B\vdash A$, we say that $A\equiv B$. If $A\to B$, $B\to A$, we say $A\leftrightarrow B$. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes. ------------------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1) : NO. The "standard" approach with *Natural Deduction* is to use only one connective per rule :

$$
\frac{\begin{array}{ccc}
[A]&&[B]\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
B&&A
\end{array}}{A \leftrightarrow B}
$$

Often, mainly for typoghrapical reasons, we may write it as :

$$
\frac{\begin{array}{ccc}
A \vdash B &&B \vdash A
\end{array}}{A \leftrightarrow B}
$$

but in this way we can "loose" the information about the discharge of the assumptions.

---

For 2), you have to recall the restriction :

> $x$ is not free in $A$, or in a hypothesis of the subderivation of $A$, other than $\varphi(x)$,

and that, with the application of $\exists$-elim rule, you have to discharge the "temporary" assumption $\varphi(x)$.

Consider the following example :

1) $\exists x (x=0)$ --- premise

2) $x=0$ --- temporary assumption [a] for $\exists$-elim : it is the $\varphi(x)$ of the rule

3) $x=0$ --- from 2) : invalid ! it is the $A$ of the rule, but it has $x$ free, where $x$ is already free in $\varphi(x)$

4) $x=0$ --- from 1), 2) and 3) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [a]

5) $\forall x (x=0)$ --- from 4) by $\forall$-intro : no open assumptions with $x$ free.

Thus, we have derived the *invalid* :

> $\exists x (x=0) \vdash \forall x(x=0)$.

---

Regarding the part of the proviso : $x$ is not free in a hypothesis of the subderivation of $A$, other than $\varphi(x)$, consider :

1) $\exists x (x=0)$ --- premise

2) $x=0$ --- assumed [a] for $\exists$-elim

3) $\exists x (x=1)$ --- premise

4) $x=1$ --- assumed [b] for $\exists$-elim

5) $x=0 \land x=1$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\land$-intro

6) $\exists x (x=0 \land x=1)$ --- from 5) by $\exists$-intro

7) $\exists x (x=0 \land x=1)$ --- from 1), 2) and 6) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [a] : invalid ! there is still the open assumption [b] with $x$ free in this sub-derivation.

Thus, we have derived the *invalid* :

> $\exists x (x=0), \exists x (x=1) \vdash \exists x (x=0 \land x=1)$.

Comment: And why is this more natural than $\begin{array}{c}
A\rightarrow B \quad B \rightarrow A\\
\hline\hline
A\leftrightarrow B
\end{array}$ (except the fact that my rule is using another connective but that hasn't to do with natural or not)?

Comment: @asdfusername - Peter Smith has already answered you in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349264/most-natural-formulation-of-the-vee-eliminating-rule).

Comment: No, he hasn't!!

Comment: The argument "A rule should not contain more than one connective" is bullshit. In a natural deduction calculus one can alway use all the usual connectives. Otherwise it wouldn't be a *natural* deduction calculus.

Comment: @asdfusername - This is not what the "founders" of Nat Ded thinked ... See e.g. Dag Prawitz, [Natural Deduction : A Proof-Theoretical Study](https://books.google.it/books?id=e0_uAAAAMAAJ) (1965), but of course you can stay with your own ideas, and define a bran new, "not bullshit", super-Natural Deduction system.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thank you ;-D I have another short question to you: Would you define the $\leftrightarrow$ "if and only if" just as abbreviation or would you define it as a own connective?

Comment: "For 1) : NO. The "standard" approach with Natural Deduction is to use only one connective per rule"

Perhaps it's fair to say that.  That said, the rule by the author can work as just as useful as the rule you cited.